# Macbook apps randomly become unresponsive

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, hdd

Recently I started to experience problems with my old MacbookPro mid 2012 which has Sierra 10.12.2, 512 GB HDD (the initial factory disk), and 16GB RAM (2x8GB, memory was upgraded from the initial 4GB).

The problem is that after few hours of normal work a random application (one of opened) become unresponsive and freeze, I see standard Apple's rolling rainbow-colored circle. It's not that the whole macbook is stuck: the mouse works perfectly fine and I can move app's window around, but inside the window nothing works. Other apps may work normally (but rarely more than one app gets frozen at the same time).
Then after about a half a minute (sometimes longer), it unfreezes and I can continue my work.

This can happen with any application but the ones I use almost always are: iTerm2, Sublime Text 3 and Google Chrome.
If this happens in Chrome I often see "Waiting for cache" in the left corner.
If I was typing something on the keyboard and the app got frozen, I can continue typing - after it unfreezes, the text will quickly appear.

I also noticed that startup/shutdown and OS updates have become considerably slower.

A silly workaround I found useful is to remove some cache folders from `~/Library/Caches`, but this doesn't work for 100% and lasts only for a few hours.

I blame the HDD, but can't be sure, can it be some misconfiguration/broken caches/etc? I don't want to go buy new SSD "just to check".
If I run disk utility, it takes a really long time to complete, like 7-8 hours but eventually reports no errors.

Are there any tests I can run to find if the problem is with the HDD. I would greatly appreciate tests which can be perfromed from a command line.

Comment: Boot into Safe mode (hold down Shift at boot). This will delete some additional system cache files. Also, 7-8 hours on a disk check is _way_ too long. Lastly, how much free space on the HDD? In any case, updating to a SSD is a real performance booster. MacOS versions later than Yosemite really like running from a SSD, which are relatively inexpensive now.

Comment: @IconDaemon I've done that and the result is that it takes a long time to boot (probably because disk check is run), and then the problem disappears for some time. But after about two  days it returns.

Comment: Does the HDD space decrease quickly before the Mac starts crawling again? MacOS doesn't like running from a almost-full HDD. You should also try the [Hardware test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to see if there are any physical problems with the Mac itself.

Comment: @IconDaemon No, I have 45% free (212 GB)

Comment: When the Disk Utility check took 7-8 hours, had you launched it from the 'Applications' folder, or were you booted to the Recovery Partition? Also, have you tested the issue in a new user account to verify whether or not it's a user-based issue or a system-wide issue?

Comment: @NYKg I ran disk utility during boot into recovery mode. Indeed, I tested on a newly created account and found that the problem reappears after some period of time